# System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument.Body.get retornou null

Tags: c#, html, winforms

Estou criando elementos HTML pelo C# utilizando o Webbrowser, não estou utilizando a propriedade URL, apenas usando código puro. Quando tento utilizar este comando:

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<head></head><body></body>";
var document = this.webBrowser1.Document;
document.Body.Style = "background-color:red;";
```

Dá esse erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto.'
>
> System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument.Body.get retornou null.

Já coloquei esse código acima, dentro do método DocumentCompleted do Webbrowser, mas só que não é chamado. Só por isso coloquei no construtor.

Como faço para que o código acima funcione?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível manipular o `Document`até que o mesmo tenha completado sua inicialização. Você pode utilizar o envento `DocumentCompleted`.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><head></head><body></body></html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
}

private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{            
    webBrowser1.Document.Body.Style = "background-color:red;";            
}
```